# Delete Specific version of Document in Alfresco

Tags: java, alfresco, opencmis

Can we delete a specific version of Document in Alfresco?? As while I am trying to delete document by my code it will delete a document with version history. I want to delete specific version of Document.

Answer (score 5):

You want [VersionService.deleteVersion(NodeRef, Version)](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/service/cmr/version/VersionService.html#deleteVersion%28org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef,%20org.alfresco.service.cmr.version.Version%29) - that will let you delete one version out of the history

Do something like:

```
VersionHistory history = versionService.getVersionHistory(nodeRef);
for (Version version : history.getAllVersions())
{
     if (version.getVersionLabel().equals("2.99"))
     {
         versionService.deleteVersion(nodeRef, version);
         break;
     }
}
```

Or:

```
VersionHistory history = versionService.getVersionHistory(nodeRef);
try {
    Version version = history.getVersion("1.42");
    versionService.deleteVersion(nodeRef, version);
} catch(VersionDoesNotExistException e) {
    System.err.println("It seems to have already gone!");
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Get the version service, ask the user which version they want to delete, then grab the version (as above) and call delete, job done!